# 2 stm32 adress does not match in proteus

Tags: stm32, i2c, slave

I am trying to communicate 2 STM32 with I2C.My configuration is as followed:

7-bit addressing mode (no dual address, only OAR1)

100khz speed

ACK enabled (on slave)

ACK disabled (on master, since only 1 byte is transferred between master/slave at any time)

on both master/slave, datasheet says GPIOB (PB6) as SCL as AF and GPIOB (PB7) as SDA as AF but PB8 and PB9 becomes logic 1 in Proteus so I use PB8 and PB9.Adress does not match.Could it be because of Proteus?

Master code:

```c
#include "stm32f10x.h" // Device header 
#include "delay.h"

void pinConfig(void);

void i2c_Master_Config(void);

void sendAdress();

int main() {

  pinConfig();
  i2c_Master_Config();
  sendAdress();




  while(1) {}
}

void pinConfig() {

  RCC->APB1ENR |= 1<<21;//Enable I2C 1 clock
  RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<2;//Enable GPIOA clock
  RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<3;//Enable GPIOB clock 
  RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<0;//Enable AFIO clock
  GPIOB->CRH |= 0x000000FF; //SCL ve SDA  AF Open Drain  SCL => PB8  
  SDA =>PB9  
}

void i2c_Master_Config() {

  RCC->APB1ENR |= 1<<21; //I2C 1 Clock Enable.  
  I2C1->CR1 |= (1 << 15);
  I2C1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 15);
  I2C1->CR2 |= 0x08; //36 Mhz peripheral clock.
  I2C1->CCR = 0x28; //100 khz clock  
  I2C1->TRISE = 0x09; //1/8MHZ= 125 ns  => 1000ns/125ns =8  => 8+1=9
  I2C1->CR1 |= (1<<0); //Peripheral enable.
}

void sendAdress() {

  volatile int temp;
  I2C1->CR1 |= 1<<8; //START bit.
  while(!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<0))); //wait until start flag is set

  I2C1->DR = 0x0B; //7 bit adress.

  while(!(I2C1->SR1 & (1<<1))); //wait until addr flag is set
  temp = I2C1->SR2; //clear addr flag.
}
```

Slave code:

```c
#include "stm32f10x.h" // Device header

void pinConfig(void);

void i2c_Slave_Config(void);

uint8_t data;

void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler() {

  volatile int temp;

  if(I2C1->SR1 &(1<<1)) { //wait until addr flag is set
    temp = I2C1->SR1; //clear addr  
    temp = I2C1->SR2; //clear addr
    GPIOA->BRR |= 1<<3;
  }
}

int main() {

  pinConfig();
  i2c_Slave_Config();

  while(1) {}
}

void pinConfig() {

  RCC->APB1ENR |= 1<<21; //I2C 1 Clock enable.
  RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<2;  //Enable GPIOA clock
  RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<3;  //Enable GPIOB clock 
  RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<0;  //Enable AFIO clock

  GPIOA->CRL |= 0x00002000; //PA3 led.
  GPIOB->CRH |= 0x000000FF; //SCL ve SDA  AF Open Drain  SCL => PB8  SDA =>PB9
  GPIOA->BSRR |= 1<<3;   //Turn off the led.
}

void i2c_Slave_Config() {

  RCC->APB1ENR |= 1<<21; //I2C 1 Clock Enable.  
  I2C1->CR1 |= (1 << 15);
  I2C1->CR1 &= ~(1 << 15);
  I2C1->CR2 |= 0x08;
  I2C1->CCR = 0x28; //100 khz clock  
  I2C1->OAR1 &= ~(1<<15); //7-bit slave adress.
  I2C1->CR2 |= 1<<9; //Interrupt enable.
  NVIC->ISER[0] |= 1<<31; //i2c1 interrupt enable.
  I2C1->OAR1 = (0x05 << 1); //Slave adress
  I2C1->CR1 |= (1<<0); //Peripheral enable.
  I2C1->CR1 |= 1<<10; //ACK bit.
}
```

Comment: How does all become wrong?Is configuration wrong?Which part wrong?İt is all written in the datasheet and the codes I saw.Tell the wrong part and let me know of course if you know

Comment: Actually almost everything - IRQ handling, setup etc.

Comment: with this way I wrote SPI,UART,ADC,LCD,Interrupt library and you say this is wrong.Are you sure about you know anything about STM32?

Comment: this stm321f103c6 .Probably you were expecting (GPIOx_OTYPER,GPIOx_MODER etc.) so They dont exist.

Comment: Is there any help?